# Distinguish between Reference product and Activity name in Brightway2 Excel importer

Tags: brightway

The brightway2 Excel importer, described [here](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2io.html#excel), seems to assume that the reference product name and the activity name are the same, which is not always the case.

Adding a reference product section to the activity metadata does not help: the linking is unable to link the `production` exchanges to the activity generating it.

Is there a workaround to using the Excel importer to import activities where the `production`exchange is not necessarily named exactly as the activity?

Answer (score 2):

Linking is done by "strategy" functions. In this case, it seems like you just need a custom function that takes the fields you want. I haven't tested it, but something like the following should be OK:

```
def match_by_reference_product(database):
    """Match using reference product instead of 'name' field."""
    def get_product_exchange(dataset):
        lst = [e for e in dataset if e['type'] == 'production']
        if len(lst) != 1:
            raise ValueError("Can't find one production exchange: {}".format(dataset))
        return lst[0]

    def get_fields(exc):
        return (
            exc['reference product'],
            exc['unit'],
            exc['location']
        )

    possibles = {
        get_fields(get_product_exchange(dataset)): (dataset['database'], dataset['code'])
        for dataset in database
    }

    for dataset in database:
        for exc in dataset['exchanges']:
            if exc['input']:
                continue
            if exc['type'] != 'technosphere':
                continue
            try:
                exc['input'] = possibles[(exc['name'], exc['unit'], exc['location'])]
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return database
```

Apply using `my_importer.apply_stragtegy(match_by_reference_product)`.

Comment: This is a great tutorial into using custom strategies.